# Is it ethical according to SO to ask the questions of a site of area51 in its existing parent SE site?

Tags: discussion, area-51, ethics

There is a site in making named "Coffee" in Area51. There is a successful cooking
site already active.

I am a newbie coffee drinker and am curious about coffee. I am finding those
questions of "Coffee" site of Area51 interesting. That site may or may not
succeed.

Is it ethical according to SO to ask the questions of a site of area51 in its existing
parent SE site, ***right now***?

Comment: Actually I wanted to know about "ethics" here. If these questions get answered on cooking site then they will be closed as duplicates on the new site if it launches.

Comment: The questions *can't* be closed as duplicates as there is no process for marking cross site duplicates. The only thing that can happen is for the "parent" site to decide that new questions on the "child" topic are now off topic.

Comment: Related reading: **[Respect the community – your own, and others’](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/03/respect-the-community-your-own-and-others/)**

Comment: *"If these questions get answered on cooking site then they will be closed as duplicates on the new site"* - No, they can't and they won't, ever.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just because there is (or will be) a dedicated site for a specific topic it doesn't mean that any related question is off-topic for another site.

I'll give an example from the Stack Overflow side of the network:

Questions about [wordpress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wordpress) or [drupal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/drupal) are accepted on Stack Overflow even though both have dedicated sites:

- https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/
- https://drupal.stackexchange.com/

When the lines are a little bit blurry but one topic is encapsulated in another it's totally fine to ask in either site as long as you're not cross posting and duplicating content.

So in short **it is acceptable to ask your coffee question on the Cooking.SE and even once the coffee site launches, it would still be ok to post your question either there or on Cooking.SE.**

---

Regarding the OP's comments related to closing as duplicates once the new site opens:

It is possible that once the coffee site is up and running that the Cooking.SE community will decide to purge all coffee related content and migrate it although as I said before, just because there is a "better" place to post such a question, it doesn't mean that it is automatically "off-topic" for it's current location. Closing a question as a duplicate on a different site doesn't really happen - what can happen is that the post is migrated and then closed but, again, it all depends on whether the community decides to take these actions.

*Ethically, as long as your intention is to add to the collective knowledge of the community - you can't go wrong.*